# the tags of a post do not display, on the other hand title and content using vuejs 3 and firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i'm new to `vuejs 3`, i used `vuejs 3` and `firebase`, i created a `posts.vue` `component`, and a `OnePost.vue` component which display the `posts`, and `getPosts.js` which allows to retrieve the `posts`, and `show.vue` which displays the details of each `post`, and `getOnePost.js` which allows you to retrieve the details of a single `post`, the problem here is that the `tags` of a `post` in a `span` are not displayed on the other hand. 'displays when I wrote `<p> {{post.tags}} </p>` it displays like this `[ "front-end", "back-end", "fullstack" ]`.

**views/posts.vue**

```
<template lang="">
    <h1>list of posts</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6" v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
            <OnePost :post="post"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</template>
<script>
import OnePost from '../components/OnePost'
import loadPosts from './../composables/posts/getPosts'
export default {
    components: { OnePost },
    setup() {

        const { posts,error,load } = loadPosts();

        load();

        return { posts }

    }
    
}
</script>
```

**OnePost.vue**

```
<template lang="">
    <h2 @click="show = !show">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <div v-if="show">
        <div class="well">
            <p>{{ extract }}</p>
            <p>{{ post.tags }}</p>
            <div class="well">
                <span v-for="tag in post.tags" class="badge badge-primary mr-2">
                    #{{ tag }}
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="my-3">
                <router-link :to="{ name: 'Show-post',params:{id: post.id} }" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">
                    Show
                </router-link>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-warning ml-2">Edit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ml-2">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
export default {
    props: ['post'],
    setup(props){

        const show = ref(true)

        const extract = computed(() => props.post.content.substring(0, 50) + '...')

        return { extract, show }

    }
    
}
</script>
```

**getPosts.js**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { db } from './../../firebase/config'

const loadPosts = () => {

    const posts = ref([])
    const error = ref(null) 
        
    const load  = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await db.collection('posts').get();
            posts.value = res.docs.map(doc => {
                return {...doc.data(), id: doc.id}
            })
            console.log(posts.value);
            
        } catch (err) {
            
           error.value = err.message
        }
        
    }

    return { posts,error,load}

} 
export default loadPosts;
```

**show.vue**

```
<template lang="">
    <div>
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router'
import getOnePost from './../composables/posts/getOnePost.js'
export default {
    setup() {
        const route = useRoute();

        const { post,error,load } = getOnePost();
        const id = route.params.id;
        load(id)

        return { post }
    }
    
}
</script>
```

**getOnePost.js**

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { db } from './../../firebase/config'

const loadPost = () => {

    const post = ref({})
    const error = ref(null) 
        
    const load  = async (id) => {
        try {
            const res = await db.collection('posts').doc(id).get();
            posts.value = { ...res.data(),id }
            
        } catch (err) {
            
           error.value = err.message
        }
        
    }

    return { post,error,load}

} 
export default loadPost;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the post is got asynchronously, so `post.tags` will be undefined at the first rendering, to solve this you've to check if the property is available by using conditional rendering `v-if="post.tags"`:

```
        <div v-if="post.tags" class="well">
            <span v-for="tag in post.tags" class="badge badge-primary mr-2">
                #{{ tag }}
            </span>
        </div>
```